# SharePoint hosted addin file not found

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am building SharePoint hosted add-in. I am trying to reference the `sp.js and sp.runtime.js` but I am getting error

`File '_/layouts/15/sp.runtime.js' was not found.   SharePointHostedAddin`

Screenshot below:

Please help.

[image]

Comment: Change your path address to /_layouts/sp.js and /_layouts/sp.runtime.js

Answer (score 0):

"_" wrong location.It should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
```

Document reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-the-sharepoint-javascript-apis-to-work-with-sharepoint-data